# Gradient of a scalar field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, scalar-fields

I know that the gradient points toward the maximum of a scalar field. If a scalar field has many maximum points, the gradient calculated in a point aims always toward the nearest maximum ? If yes, why ?

Comment: The gradient points locally towards the place you must walk to find the fastest changing function values.

Comment: No it only points in the direction where the function increases fastest **locally**. You will need to follow the gradient along a path to find a local maximum and you have found it when the gradient becomes 0 and the hessian is positive definite.

Comment: Wait did i write positive definite? I mean negative definite of course if it is a local maximum we are searching for..

Comment: To put mathreadler’s comment a bit differently, the gradient doesn’t point at *any* maximum of a scalar field, except by coincidence. It gives the direction in which the function is increasing the fastest at any particular point.